# Solr lucene search only first word in a sentence - need query

Tags: solr

I am searching data which matches only that sentence which starts with the search key.

Ex:

```
search key "what"
```

result : DESIRED ONE

```
**what** is your name
**what** are you doing
**what** is that

etc.
```

How i am getting now is

```
Is that **what** you want 
some text before **what** 

etc.
```

i am using EdgeNGram as well..But it is giving me the second one.
Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex 'starts with query' `q:(name:/what.*/)` will yield results where the name field start with 'what'

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the WhitespaceTokenizer. You should try using the KeywordTokenizer with EdgeNGram from the left end.

If you're trying to implement auto suggest, have a look at the [Suggester](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) component.

Comment: hi, i tried with the link related to suggester. I am getting only that word which the user typed. For EX: if my search field as the value "what is your name" and if search is w OR wh, it is giving me only "what" and if someone searches for yo it is giving me only "your". So here i want when w is searched i want entire string and nothing on "yo"

Comment: whitespace OR keyword tokenizer didn't make difference !

Comment: Ya Suggester works on tokens rather than the field value itself. I'm not sure why Keyword tokenizer doesn't work, it would preserve the whole value, and ngram from the front, which seems to be exactly what you want. Worst case, you could give facet.prefix a shot http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.prefix

Comment: i had checked on this facet.. looked complicated and lengthy....thought if it can be solved in query string. Is there a way to be controlled through query

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following trick: add the following line to your field definition:

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
  pattern="^(.*)$" replacement="AAAA $1" />
```

This will add the "AAAA" token to both your index and query. This way you can match the beginning of an indexed string.

More info here:

- http://robotlibrarian.billdueber.com/2012/03/boosting-on-exactish-anchored-phrase-matching-in-solr-sst-4/
- example: https://github.com/billdueber/solr_stupid_tricks/blob/SST4/solr/conf/schema.xml (search for "text_l")
- http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_leighton_fisher/2012/01/stupid-lucene-tricks-exact-match-starts-with-ends-with.html